# Double click event for TreeViewer column header?

Tags: treeview, jface, double-click

All I would like to do is to add double-click-to-sort at a JFace TreeViewer column.  I could find the question asked in Eclipse forum since May 2010 but no response so far.

So far I have tried:

```
column.addListener(SWT.MouseDoubleClick, listener);  // Not working, listener never called

treeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener();  // Work in the item, not column header
```

Am I missing something?

Any advice is apprecated.

Hei

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked this was still not possible with SWT 3.7. Like the documentation states, `TreeColumns` and `TableColumns` only send `Move`, `Resize` and `Selection` events. Plus, column headers can now (well, since 3.5 or so) display the control's context menu. But there's nothing to detect a double click on a column header.

Since you seem to need this for sorting, does it have to be a double click? The `Selection` event (i.e. single click) of a column is the common way to do that.

Comment: I am using the Selection (single click) event to do it at the moment.  If a user is operating the top row, it is often a mis-click and trigger a resort.

Comment: I see. If you really, really want to use a double click, you could try to implement it yourself using the `Selection` event and measuring the time between two events. If the difference is below your threshold then it's a double click.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion.  Sadly it is not even firing the 2nd click of my fack-double click.  Seems a bit lag (or a feature indeed?).  My setup is Win7, Java 1.6, Eclipse 3.6.

Comment: Just fired a bug for ecilpse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=369174